# Concurrent Transactions to Mysql Database From two Different application pointing to same databse

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, spring-transactions

I am getting duplicate entry exception while inserting one record into database(my sql), finally I found out how the exception occured.

It is due to two different web applications (different context) pointing to same database and trying to insert a record at a time or two seconds later. Can you guys please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you share what they are trying to insert ?

Comment: I think you need to lock the table on insert.  The Hibernate documentation has a section on Locking:  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html